# Xamarin C# Listener

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin, can someone show me what the equivalent c# code is for the following

```
mLoginFormView.Animate().SetDuration(200).Alpha(
                show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

I know how to set the listener to the class and implement `Animator.IAnimatorListener` but I want to know if it is possible to do it using an anonymous class?

Comment: When you say "do it like above" are you referring to the use of an anonymous class? If so, then not really. C# does not support implementing an interface in an anonymous type. But most bindings from Xamarin expose Android listeners as C# events to avoid the need. For example, Android's button has a `Clicked` event that can be used instead of `setOnClickListener`.

Comment: Yes, sorry the anonymous class.  In this example I want two separate animation listeners in the same class but I'm not sure how to differentiate between the two animations when OnAnimationEnd gets called.

Comment: Java code uses listeners, while Xamarin converts them to native C# events which you should subscribe using .NET event handlers (delegates).

Comment: If it's possible, I would suggest using event handlers and subscribing two different event handlers. It could be 2 different methods in your class, which makes differentiating easy.

Answer (score 0):

It works almost the same as the code above.

```
 mLoginFormView.Animate()
    .SetDuration(200)
    .Alpha(show ? 0 : 1)
    .SetListener(this);
```

And in your Activity/Fragment, implement the `Android.Animation.Animator.IAnimatorListener`.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity, Android.Animation.Animator.IAnimatorListener
{
    //other interface implemented methods...
    public void OnAnimationEnd(Android.Animation.Animator animation)
    {
        //do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use another class that implements the interface, but it's pretty normal to use the current Activity/Fragment.

Comment: I understand this way as mentioned, my problem is, I am trying to use two animation listeners in the same class and in OnAnimationEnd at class level, I have no way of identifying between the two

Comment: Then I would use two different classes that implement the interface.

Comment: it'll be in your best interest to create a special listener class and set it, it's far cleaner to do that route.